# Salesforce Data Via API coming over as GMT

Tags: api, metadata-api, data

We've connected our SFDC Datamodel to Sisense and the data is coming over as GMT rather than EST.  anyone encountered this issue and was able to address it?  the Org is set to EST under the General Settings.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: All times are stored as GMT in Salesforce. What timezone is the user that authenticates for the integration set to?

Comment: To add to Eric's answer, if you have the time in GMT or UTC, you can always offset it based on the user's timezone. That's the benefit of storing it that way.

Answer (score 2):

The API always returns GMT-based date/time values. This fixes any problems like Daylight Savings Time (where there's an hour overlap in the Fall, for example), as GMT does not observe these seasonal time shifts. Also, most computer languages have built-in functions to convert to and from GMT, so this is usually not a problem.